# CKEditor configuration in django admin

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need to add richtextfield to my admin panel in Django, so I choose CKEditor, but I've got some problems with configuration:

When I try to move a row in django administration panel (with Enter key) editor for some reason add `p` tag to my text, that I don't need (i mean in admin editor, not in template). Can I somehow deactivate it? Or replace with `br` tag?

[image]

I use default configuration of CKEditor.

settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}
```

models.py

```
class Section_1(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    text = RichTextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    ytlink = models.URLField(blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Секция 1'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Секция 1'
```

integration in template:

```
<div class="main-screen__middle-title">
{% for sec_1 in sec_1 %}
{% if sec_1.order == 1 %}
<h4 class="main-screen__middle-title_active" data-mScreen="mscreen{{ 
sec_1.order }}">{{ sec_1.text }}</h4>
{% else %}
<h4 data-mScreen="mscreen{{ sec_1.order }}">{{ sec_1.text }}</h4>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

</div>
```

So when I open template without `{{ sec_1.text| safe }}` I see this:

[image]

if I use it, CKEditor just ignore `h4` tag:

[image]

Questions are:

1) How to remove auto adding `'p'` in admin panel?

2) How, if I use `|safe` to my variable, to make it not ignore external html-tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you prefer to not wrap the text in anything**, you can choose to insert a line break tag because by default it takes `p` tag for wrapping.

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

> You need to add below line in **config.js** file for CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config)
{
   config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

   ...
};
```

or else if you want to wrap in `div` tag then,

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but where i can find this file? May be i install ckeditor not properly?

Comment: Try putting the code in `settings.py` file. It will overwrite.

Comment: yep, but it looks a little bit different to django  CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
        'enterMode': 2, 
    }

Comment: You can do both way, this is done uaing a function. If the solution helped you, then you can select this answer. Let me know if anything else is there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find an answer for django:

settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
        **'enterMode': 2,** 
    },
    'awesome_ckeditor':{
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','- 
','Link','Unlink','Anchor','-', 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize','-', 
'Image' ]
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It worked for me. Saved my time. :) But sure without asterisks ;)